# CSS : Centering multiple lines of text in a DIV

Tags: css, html

Two questions in one. This is a first for me lol

Anyway, as you are probably aware, centering content vertically is such a pain in website development. I already know how to center a single line of text in a div thanks to line-height. However my problem is that I want to center more than one line of text in a div.

Does anyone know how? I'm starting from scratch here so there is no code unfortunately.

Comment: As there are quite a few hacks for different situations, please start first without centering anything, provide that code, and ask again.

Comment: display: table-cell is one - , we can set vertical  align middle then, but screws up other layout settings possibly

Comment: another - with a height on the container, add another wrapper div inside with 'margin : auto auto', like we do the the horizontal align

Comment: @Johannes : This is all there is for the DIV's CSS. [height, width, margin-left, margin-right and background-color] All that is inside this DIV is text. No <p>. No images. Just text. That's why I said there was no code. There is no code that modifies the DIV in terms of alignment in any way

Comment: YOu won#t get far without any additional (smentically useless) wrappers I guess. If you have a fixed height. @RobSedgwick's second suggestion could work (if you wrap the text inside another div).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eUfE3/ - for the table-cell one

Comment: auto auto doesn't work - will post up the vertical-align: middle; one

Comment: I've tried the table-cell and it completely breaks it the DIV for me.
The margin auto auto didn't work but it didn't break the DIV either. I've also tried Allan's approaches

Comment: Yeah the table-cell is awkward if trying to combine the layout divs with your content styling divs - to use it you would have separate them and use the table-cell divs as a div within your display:block layout divs

Comment: So what is the vertical-align method?

Comment: @JeremyBeare, sorry - in combo with display:table-cell, we need vertical-align: middle; - similar to the  inline 'valign' of the bad old days : ) -its in the answer I posted up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css `display:table-cell` method

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/eUfE3/

```
    <div>

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
       . Mauris tempus blandit egestas. Phasellus lacinia non lorem
        hendrerit sagittis. Aenean iaculis sit amet erat sed feugia
        t. Cras vulputate odio nec ultricies facilisis. Phasellus a
        uctor commodo ligula nec tincidunt. In non leo facilisis p
        urus hendrerit volutpat vitae at nunc

    </div>
```

CSS

```
div { display:table-cell;  vertical-align: middle; height:300px; }
```

---

**Update/**

As comments, yes using this is a killer if we are using these divs to create layout AND style content at the same time.

Here is an example were we can keep the layout divs and employ divs within to present content.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sPG8j/2/

It is perhaps one of many solutions, but ( i'd say ) the simplest , perhaps arguably a good idea to separate 'content styling divs' from 'layout creating divs' anyway ... : ? CMS etc ..

**Update:**

This could be handy too ( jquery shorthand for ease ) ( say we don't want to go through and re markup all our content )

http://jsfiddle.net/mWdCT/1/

```
$(".layout").wrapInner( "<div class='data'><div class='content'></div></div>" );
```

CSS in the example

```
.data { display:table; height:100%; width:100%; }
.content { display:table-cell;  vertical-align: middle; height:100%; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are clones of this div and they are all merging together as a table

Comment: sure @JeremyBeare  , updated the idea/suggestion / one way to do this I suppose

Comment: How do I move the cell 8px away from the left and right?

Comment: Hi @JeremyBeare, we need 'border-spacing' for elements with 'table' type displays - http://jsfiddle.net/JGDT3/1/

Comment: Great stuff @JeremyBeare!

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, it's a pain, there's no easy answer. You'll most likely have to define your use case better before you start, since different techniques may break in different ways. Try these tutorials:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/