# Centering text inside the block element

Tags: html, css

How to centering text inside the `label` tag. E.g. consider the follwoing markup:

```
<label for='txt'>static text
    <input type="text" id='txt' value="" />
</label>
```

and styles

```
label{
    display:block;
    height:200px;
}
```

There is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uy4Fc/1/) example. How to centering label's content in my case?

Comment: Do you mean vertical align ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811622/css-centering-multiple-lines-of-text-in-a-div/

Comment: If it is 1 line of text - for vertical alignment , set your `line-height:200px` ( *the same as your `height`* ) - PellePenna and Kevin have examples below

Answer (score 3):

```
label{
    display:block;
    height:200px;
    line-height: 200px;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/uy4Fc/2/

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css:

```
line-height:200px
```

Like this:

```
label{
    display:block;
    height:200px;
    line-height:200px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
label{
    display:block;
    height:200px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/uy4Fc/3/

Answer (score 0):

I use label next to input, not input inside label. For that, there is working example of both vertical/horizontal center...

http://jsfiddle.net/uy4Fc/1/

CSS:

```
label{
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 0;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML:
    Text